# Sitecore User Group Brazil - February 27, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Date/Time BRT: Tuesday, February 27, 2018, Starts at 7:00 PM

Date/Time EST: Tuesday, February 27, 2018, Starts at 5:00 PM

Date/Time UTC: Tuesday, February 27, 2018, Starts at 22:00 PM

RSVP: http://meetu.ps/e/DSfx6/yrwpQ/f

Join us @Florianopolis, Tuesday Feb 27, 2018 for our next Brazil Sitecore User Group (SUGBR).

Presentations

- **Automated Migration to Sitecore** with Sitecore MVP Eduardo Moraes
- **Pushing Sitecore 9 Dynamic Placeholders to the edge with a Bootstrap Grid System Implementation** with Sitecore MVP Rodrigo Peplau

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 12 hours